# ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

i've been following rails guide on creating and mounting an engine [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html).Created blog post and when i tried to comment ,it returned "ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in Blorgh::CommentsController#create " error.
Comment controller

```
    require_dependency "blorgh/application_controller"

module Blorgh
  class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    def create
      @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
      @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment])
      flash[:notice] = "Comment has been created!"
      redirect_to posts_path
    end
  end
end
```

and here is comment model

```
 module Blorgh
  class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base

  end
end
```

how to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are using rails 4. You need to mark all the required parameters
here it goes :

```
   def create
      @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
      @comment = @post.comments.create(post_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Comment has been created!"
      redirect_to posts_path
    end

    def post_params
      params.require(:blorgh).permit(:comment)
    end
```

hope  [this link](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/3/21/strong-parameters/)  helps...

Comment: now i'm getting "ActionController::ParameterMissing in Blorgh::CommentsController#create " error!

Comment: i was under expectation that you have a `blorgh` key in your params, it can be anything, I guess heres a detailed explanation of wat you have to do: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/3/21/strong-parameters/

Comment: How did you solve ActionController::ParameterMissing in Blorgh::CommentsController#create ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. So if you disect the params hash it easy to see the nested comment params with text key.  Seems the tutorial is for Rails 3, so for the rails 4 way with trusted params the changes needed is to add the comment_params method as below.

```
Parameters:

  {"utf8"=>"✓",
  "authenticity_token"=>"uOCbFaF4MMAHkaxjZTtinRIOlpMj2QSOYf+Ugn5EMUI=",
  "comment"=>{"text"=>"asfsadf"},
  "commit"=>"Create Comment",
  "post_id"=>"1"}

    def create
      @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
      @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Comment has been created!"
      redirect_to posts_path
    end

    private

      # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
      def comment_params
        params.require(:comment).permit(:text)                
      end
```

Comment: OK so a good lesson for me too.
Follow the correct guide for the rails version your working with.

At time of writing this comment this is the rails 4 engine guide.
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html