# Unable to clear Rails ForbiddenAttributesError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I've started getting [ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/ForbiddenAttributesError.html), and I can't figure out why, and cannot easily clear it:

```
> Product.new(params[:product])
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError: ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError
from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activemodel-4.1.5/lib/active_model/forbidden_attributes_protection.rb:21:in `sanitize_for_mass_assignment'

> h = params[:product]
=> {"title"=>"a", "description"=>"b"}

> Product.new(h)
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError: ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

> h.respond_to?(:permitted?)
=> true

> h.permitted?
=> false

> h.permit!
=> {}

> Product.new(h)
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError: ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

> h
=> {"title"=>"a", "description"=>"b", "permit"=>{}}

> h.permitted?
=> false

> params[:product].class
=> Hashie::Mash

> h.class
=> Hashie::Mash
```

So I found I need copy it into a `ActionController::Parameters` object :

```
> s = ActionController::Parameters.new(h)
=> {"title"=>"a", "description"=>"b"}

> s.permitted?
=> false

> s.permit!
=> {"title"=>"a", "description"=>"b"}

> Product.new(s)
=> ok
```

This is being called from an API end point, not a controller.

The model is very plain, just validations and associations.

Using Rails v4.1.5

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19509573/activemodelforbiddenattributeserror

Comment: Slightly different @axelTetzlaff, as that is going via the Controller, here I am calling AR from an API end point. 
Also, there is no solution in that thread that answers my problem, so I don't think its a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Either do

```
Product.new(params[:product].permit!)
```

or create new private method which permits your attributes like -

```
 def permit_params
   params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description)
end
```

Comment: Your first suggestion works. With the second, I guess your suggestion was to put `permit_params` in the controller? Of which it would have to be explicitly called! And as I stated, I am not going via a controller but an API. Putting it in my API class gives me `params.require(:product) => TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into String`, or `params.require("product") => LoadError: cannot load such file -- product`.